# PowerShell and SharePoint Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Using PowerShell I want to check Searchable,Retrievable,Queryable property under Business Data.

How can I do that in Search Schema? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try someting like this

```
    $searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
    $categories = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –SearchApplication $searchapp 
    $bdCategory = $categories | ? {$_.Name -eq "Business Data" }

    $bdCategory.Retrievable = $true

    $bdCategory.Queryable =  $true

    $bdCategory.FullTextQueriable =  $true


    $bdCategory.Update()
```

To see all methods and properties you can use type this

```
$bdCategory | gm
```

Comment: But it is not working for searchable.
   $categories = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –SearchApplication $searchapp 
   $bdCategory = $categories | ? {$_.Name -eq "Business Data" }
   $bdCategory.Searchable = $true
   $bdCategory.Queryable =  $true
   
   $bdCategory.Update()                                                     Error:Property 'Searchable' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

Comment: Error: Property 'Searchable' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

Comment: for searchable you must use the FullTextQueriable property.